# Obtain a NSArray of NSDictionary, from another one, with a subset of the original set of keys

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

What's a smart way to obtain from this NSArray of NSDictionary:

```
[
{
Key1: Value1,
Key2: Value2,
Key3: Value3,
Key4: Value4
},
{
Key1: Value11,
Key2: Value12,
Key3: Value13,
Key4: Value14
},
{
Key1: Value21,
Key2: Value22,
Key3: Value23,
Key4: Value24
}
]
```

another NSArray of NSDictionary that contains a subset of the original set of keys. For example:

```
[
    {
    Key1: Value1,
    Key3: Value3
    },
    {
    Key1: Value11,
    Key3: Value13
    },
    {
    Key1: Value21,
    Key3: Value23
    }
    ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took the liberty of creating an initial array to work from...

```
NSArray* allKeys = @[@"key1",@"key2",@"key3",@"key4",@"key5"];
NSArray* allObjs = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e"];
NSMutableArray* originalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    NSRange subRange = NSMakeRange(0, i+1);
    [originalArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[allObjs subarrayWithRange:subRange] forKeys:[allKeys subarrayWithRange:subRange]]];
}
NSLog(@"origianl array = %@",originalArray);

NSArray* keys = @[@"key1",@"key3"];
__block NSMutableArray* newArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
[originalArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [newArr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[obj objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]] forKeys:keys]];
}];

NSLog(@"new array = %@",newArr);
```

which gives the following before and after:

```
2013-09-16 13:20:14.129 GammonPos[910:11303] origianl array = (
    {
    key1 = a;
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key2 = b;
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key2 = b;
    key3 = c;
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key2 = b;
    key3 = c;
    key4 = d;
}
)
2013-09-16 13:20:14.131 GammonPos[910:11303] new array = (
    {
    key1 = a;
    key3 = "<null>";
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key3 = "<null>";
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key3 = c;
},
    {
    key1 = a;
    key3 = c;
}
```

)

Comment: Don't see why this is a _worse_ answer than the accepted one, which will raise an NSInvalidArgumentException if it cannot find an object with one of the keys (cause it will try to add nil to subDictionary).

Comment: I prefer this solution 'cause is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the array and for each dictionary, create a new dictionary using only the keys you want. Add these new dictionaries to a new array.

i.e

```
// Assume initialArray is the array you start with
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[initialArray count]];

for (NSDictionary *dict in initialArray) {
    NSDictionary *subDictionary = @{@"Key1" : [dict objectForKey:@"Key1"],
                                    @"Key3" : [dict objectForKey:@"Key3"]};
    [newArray addObject:subDictionary];
}
```

And now `newArray` will be contain dictionaries with only the keys you specify.

Comment: Smart in terms of what? You could do this concurrently using the NSArray block enumeration methods if speed is a concern, you could wrap this code sample in an autorelease pool if memory is a concern. This works. It's simple, and performant. Anything else you can tweak after profiling and finding real hotspots.